# Adhoc and Appstore release compiling doesn't work

Tags: ios, compilation, release, building

In debug scheme my xcode project works fine on simulator and devices. But in release scheme(both adhoc and appstore), it stops and doesn't go on on compiling phase. (at the last source file.)

i.e. the project shows "Building XXXX: XXX | Compiling 128 of 128 source files".
and doesn't work anymore.

Only I can cancel building.
Whats the matter?

Comment: What version of Xcode?  What version of OSX?

Comment: I'm using OSX Mavericks 10.9.5 and Xcode Version 6.2 (6C131e). And I made release archives with other xcode projects, so I think its the projects problem. Thanks for any help.

Comment: And now it shows "Building XXXX:XXXX | Compiling 77 of 128 files", and stops.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. The reason was from the huge function, I have 3000+ line function, it stops compilation in release scheme. I'm so sorry for everybody.